Kprobe and tracepoint, which one is triggered first?
Assuming you have 2 eBPF programs one is of type BPF_PROG_TYPE_TRACEPOINT and the other BPF_PROG_TYPE_KPROBE. The tracepoint attaches to sys_enter_execve and kprobe would attach to the same syscall.
Is there a particular order of execution here? I would assume the tracepoint attaches just before the kernel enters the syscall and the kprobe attaches on the exact entry point of the syscall but I'm not so sure and couldn't find documentation about it.

Did you consider testing it?

For syscall hooking particularly, raw tracepoing is being triggered first. The raw tracepoint sys_enter is specified at entry point of all syscalls (do_syscall_x64 ...), then to be dispatched to the actual handler (eg: __x64_sys_execve or __ia32_sys_execve).
Double-check it on your own:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L368
